# Automatic linebreak within table

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I currently use the `tabular` package to create my table. One of my columns has several lines of text, so I need a line break mechanism. I do currently have a working mechanism.

```
\usepackage{makecell}
...
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c| }
        \hline
        \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Goal} & \textbf{Results} & \textbf{Methods used} & \textbf{Validity} \\
        \hline
        VS Code       & \makecell[l]{Desktop-\acs{IDE} with plugin\\mechanism and language server\\integration \cite{vscode01, vscode02}.} & ? & ? & ? \\
        \hline
        Cloud9 IDE    & \makecell[l]{Cloud-based \acs{IDE} with real time\\team collaboration capabilities with\\a computation and storage based\\pricing system \cite{cloud-ide02, cloud9ide01}.} & ? & ? & ? \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

The annoying thing is that I manually have to do the line break. So if I change the text somewhere in the middle, I have to readjust everything. What would be much better is a function like `\makecell{...}` that automatically does its line break as needed.

Is there a function somewhere in Latex for automatic line break?

Comment: `\makecell` allows for line breaks, but they have to be hand-done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple methods to get automatic line breaks

- use columns of a fixed with, e.g. `p{1cm}`
- use the `tabularx` package and `X` columns which will automatically choose column widths to fill the desired width for the whole table

Furthermore I suggest to use the `booktabs` package for a nice table layout.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{1.2cm}Xc>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.6cm}c@{}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Goal} & \textbf{Results} & \textbf{Methods used} & \textbf{Validity} \\
      \midrule
      VS Code  & Desktop-IDE with plugin mechanism and language server integration. & ? & ? & ? \\
      \addlinespace
            Cloud9 IDE & Cloud-based IDE with real time team collaboration capabilities with a computation and storage based pricing system. & ? & ? & ? \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]